# What are popular genre of music in U.S

Tags: genre, rock, pop, music-business

I am trying to find out popularity of music genres. [This page](http://www.statista.com/chart/1783/album-sales-in-the-us-by-genre/) provides the popularity of music genre, but its little old, can anyone share the ranking of genres based on popularity?

Comment: Read Billboard Magazine. This industry trade publication has been studying, tabulating and reporting on this since the 1930s. http://www.billboard.com

Comment: Bluesy Jazz, or Jazz Blues.  Research "Naughty Jack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.statista.com/statistics/188910/us-music-album-sales-by-genre-2010) shows album sales broken down into genres in America.

Is this of any use?

It is something close to what you already have, but shows it up to 2014 (from 2008).

Comment: Album sales don't nessesary correlate to popularity, especially physical album sales numbers.  One genre could have more albums sold,  but be less popular when everything is counted.

Comment: @jacobSwanson You make a fair point, if you think about back catalogue sales, or people buying albums they have lost or had on different formats etc., but I think, generally, album sales will give a reasonable indication of genre popularity.